# Return the name of a function in lowercase

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project **(ASP.net MVC)** i have to **return** the name of a **function** (CSV File i read in) in **lowercase**. Because for now i have grouped the functions and it return functions with the same name (sometimes in lower case and sometimes in upper case). I don't know how to solve this problem?

[image]

```
//HomeController
public List<DescFunctionDataDTO> DescFunctionData()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DescFunctionData");

    var descItemsStamp = db.ChartDatas
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Function });

    var descItems = descItemsStamp
        .Select(x => new DescFunctionDataDTO
        {
            function = x.Select(b => b.Function).Distinct(),
            functionavg = Math.Round(x.Average(y => y.Duration), 2),
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.functionavg)
        .ToList();
    return descItems;
}

//DTO
public class DescFunctionDataDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<string> function { get; set; }
    public double functionavg { get; set; }
}

//JS-File
function showDescDuration() {

    $.getJSON(`/Home/DescFunctionData`)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);

            $('#rankingMax').find("tr:gt(0)").fadeOut().empty();
            var i = 1;
            for (let item of data) {
                console.log('loop');

                $('<tr>').appendTo('#rankingMax')
                    .append($('<td>').html("#"+i))
                    .append($('<td>').html(item.function))
                    .append($('<td>').html(item.functionavg + " ms"));
                i++;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: have you tried `item.function.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: Looks like your classmate has already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147121/how-to-group-by-tolower

Comment: @OwenPauling haha ups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pre-defined function string.ToLower() like this,

```
var descItemsStamp = db.ChartDatas
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Function });

var descItems = descItemsStamp
    .Select(x => new DescFunctionDataDTO
    {
        function = x.Select(b => b.Function.ToLower()).Distinct(),
        functionavg = Math.Round(x.Average(y => y.Duration), 2),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.functionavg)
    .ToList();
return descItems;
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me also how could i filter the functions that only 1 example of every function appears. e.g only 1 time .Index, only 1 time .Login, ....

Comment: @MarkoKopuz Read up on `First`.